# Store the reordering of elements in a model in MVC app

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC website where client wants to reorder the element on a create report page and upon clicking save the ordering should stay, in my case it is going back to it's original ordering.

I am trying to sort the elements using this:

```
$("#InputTable tbody").sortable().disableSelection();
```

We have action methods (HttpPost) Create, where the view model is passed and inside the VM the list of elements are stored.
Any help here please?

Comment: The sortable docs have events and methods to get array of sorted element ids. Then it's just a matter of where you want to store them...local per user or on server?

Comment: Should be local per user. I am trying to do an ajax call with action and controller name, but the model element is not sorted.

Comment: $("#InputTable tbody").sortable({
update: function(event, ui) {
var stats = "";
$("#InputTable").find(".ui-sortable").each(function () {

})
}
})

Comment: So if you want local... put array in localStorage. Then when page loads retrieve it and sort the elements with JS. Are you able to get a sorted array from plugin?

Comment: When the user logs out and come back to the same page, will that order remain with local Storage?

Comment: Yes so long as same device and same browser. Otherwise would need to store on server

Comment: To store on server, do I need to create a new controller action method and pass that in ajax call?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to get a sorted array from jQUERY sortable?

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray Can use `$(this)` inside your `update` callback. If having trouble create a live demo in a forkable sandbox site